# Running exec command php

Tags: php, exec

I have just installed pdf2htmlEX without any issues. If I run the command on the server it works fine. So I know the library itself is doing what it is supposed to do. If I run the command in `php` via the `exec` function nothing happens. I assume `exec` is used in this instance??

**In PHP**

```
// doesn't work
$output = exec('pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 pdf/test.pdf');
// doesn't work
$output = shell_exec('pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 pdf/test.pdf');
```

If I run a general command in the `exec` function it works fine, so I know `exec` is enabled and working as expected.

```
// works fine
$exec =  exec('pwd', $output);
print_r($output);
```

**Direct on Command Line not in PHP**

```
// works and generates the file as expected.
pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 pdf/test.pdf
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Command line reference for library
https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki/Quick-Start

EDIT:
After some further digging, it could be that the `php` script runs as a different user to the command line. My question would then be how do I check/fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the output html path and file name in your command :

Most of pdf_to_something packages usage with exec() is `package_name [options] <input-filename> <output-filename>`

```
$path = 'path/to/your/folder/';

$command = 'pdf2htmlEX '.$path.'test.pdf '.$path.'test.html';

exec($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following and check if your file is created in working directory.

```
exec('pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 pdf/test.pdf',$output);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tired this and it didn't work. I think it may be due to the php script being executed as a different user to the command line. The command line has permission and the script doesn't. Not sure how to fix though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411356/exec-runs-via-command-line-but-not-web

Answer (score 0):

`pdf2htmlEX` doesn't output anything.

```
$cmd=  "pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 test/test.pdf";
exec($cmd, $output);
```

Will create a `test.html` file in the current directory.

Are you expecting something else?

Note: i've tested this on ubuntu by installing `pdf2htmlEX` with

```
sudo apt-get install pdf2htmlex
```

---

To get the output,

```
$a = file_get_contents("test.html"); 
echo $a;
```

Comment: It's isn't outputting the file test.html when running the command in php, but does when run from the command prompt.

Comment: I've also ran it from a gnome-terminal and still no output. In both cases, the `.html` file was created. You can do a `$a = file_get_contents("test.html"); echo $a;` if you want to see it.

Comment: The file is never created when executed in php for me. I think it may be due to the php script being executed as a different user to the command line. The command line has permission and the script doesn't. Not sure how to fix though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411356/exec-runs-via-command-line-but-not-web

Comment: is your folder writeable? it needs to be. You can copy your php code in `/tmp` and test there.

Comment: The folder is set to 777

Comment: Try chmod 777 -R foldername/

Comment: Just added some debugging to the exec and getting the error `pdf2htmlEX: command not found` ????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105437/discussion-between-alex-tartan-and-steve).